# How do I pass an environment variable to a Netbeans Makefile on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, netbeans, ubuntu, makefile, environment-variables

I'm using Netbeans on Linux (Ubuntu 9.04) to build a C project.

How do I pass in an environment variable so that's it's visible to the Makefile?

If I do a normal `export MYVAR="xyz"` and then run `make` from the command line this works fine of course.

But Netbeans doesn't seems to use the `.bashrc` environment, so if I click "build" in Netbeans, the make fails.

Interestingly, the problem doesn't seem to occur on MacOSX - I've added the variable to `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`, and that value *is* visible to Netbeans.

I found [this post](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic7579.html) which suggested modifying `~/netbeans-6.8/etc/netbeans.conf`.  I've tried this, by adding `-J-DMYVAR=xyz` to the end of `netbeans_default_options`, ie:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xverify:none -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-XX:MaxPermSize=200m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-DMYVAR=xyz"
```

But this didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:**

This answer is possibly not valid for Unity-based flavours of Ubuntu.

---

The issue is actually nothing to do with NetBeans - it's related to the Ubuntu (ie Gnome) Launcher.

As [this blog post](http://patrick.wagstrom.net/weblog/2007/10/22/gnome-environment-variables/) explains, you need to add variables to the rather obscure `~/.gnomerc` (No Mercy? :) file in order for them to be passed to applications started with Launcher!

So just edit `~/.gnomerc` and add the variables as you would to `~/.bashrc`, eg:

```
export MYVAR="xyz"
```

and logout/login.

Comment: Hi, your prescription didn't help me. I set environment variables in the `.bashrc`, and `make` picks them up and compiles correctly when I call it from command line. However, exactly the same makefile fails in the NetBeans (7.4), because the makefile, executed from the NetBeans, doesn't see any environment variables (besides most basic ones - HOME, PATH etc)

Comment: @AlekseyYakovlev Yeah, this probably doesn't work on Unity-based Ubuntu versions, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yes - I'm on Ubuntu 3.11.0-15. So, what would you suggest in this case?