# Ant not able to find environment variables when compiling Maven project in NetBeans

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, maven, netbeans, ant

I am trying to compile an open source application 'OSCAR McMASTERS' on Ubuntu box. I am using NetBeans as my editor. If I use the following command from console it compiles successfully:

```
mvn clean install
```

but if I try to build it from IDE it show following exception:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3:run(jspc)
on project oscar: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred
while executing this line: /home/admin/oscar11/oscar/jspc.xml:18: Cannot find 
/home/admin/oscar11/oscar/${env.CATALINA_HOME}/bin/catalina-tasks.xml imported 
from /home/admin/oscar11/oscar/jspc.xml
```

though I have defined `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE` variables in my `.bashrc` file and has also restarted the machine.

EDIT:- I have used following messages in build file:

```
<echo message="${env.CATALINA_HOME}"/>
<echo message="${env.JAVA_HOME}"/>
```

it outputs value for `JAVA_HOME` correctly but for `CATALINA_HOME` it show `${env.CATALINA_HOME}`.

Comment: can you execute the ant script in verbose mode (-v), this should list all properties ant knows

Comment: @oers sure will try this. Do I need to specify the variables at some other place than `.bashrc` for IDE or ANT to be able to read them?

Comment: I think it should work, which version of ant are you using? The [doc](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) says that ant 1.8.2, is a bit improved when reading environment variables.

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003891/netbeans-ant-environment-variables)

Comment: @oers It is compiling fine from console, but I don't know how to set `-v` parameter in IDE :(

Comment: never tried ant with netbeans, does [this](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqAntShortcut) help? Do you start Netbeans from the bash-shell(if not have you tried)? Perhaps you have the set CATALINA_HOME somewhere else in your LINUX (same place as JAVA_HOME?), if you just start it by a GUI-Click (which might not invoke bash-shell and .bashrc).

Comment: @oers this seems the case as JAVA_HOME is also set in same place as CATALINA_HOME.

Answer (score 0):

I had defined `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE` variables in `.bashrc`. But when I started `NetBeans` from launcher it was not able to find environment variables. I started it from console (terminal) and everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Gnome (eg on Ubuntu) you need to set environment variables in `~/.gnomerc` to pass them to applications launched from the desktop.

See: [How do I pass an environment variable to a Netbeans Makefile on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057605/how-do-i-pass-an-enviroment-variable-to-a-netbeans-makefile-on-ubuntu)