# NetBeans/Maven/Ant Build Script Errors - Environment Variables (Linux)

Tags: linux, maven, netbeans, ant

I've been tasked with maintaining a large Java/C++ project, using NetBeans (7.0.1) and Maven/Ant for building, all running on CentOS 6.

I am currently having an issue with the build scripts.

The script is Maven, but calls an ant task:

```
<!-- create jar launch script -->
<echo file="${techsas.home}/run-exe-jar"
  message="#!/bin/bash${line.separator}java -jar -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///${TECHSAS_HOME}/log4j.xml bin/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar" append="false">
</echo>
```

The problem is with the first line. Running the script will result in this error:

```
BUILD ERROR
--------------------------------------------------
An Ant BuildException has occured: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/techsas/NetbeansProjects/<snip>/${TECHSAS_HOME}/run-exe-jar (No such file or director)
```

$TECHSAS_HOME is a valid environment variable - running

```
echo $TECHSAS_HOME
```

at the command line will give the correct value.

I'm new to NetBeans and Maven - my research online hasn't turned up any solutions. I guess probably I'm making some fundamental error here.

NetBeans seems to have trouble resolving the ${TECHSAS_HOME} variable - although I don't know why it's appending it to the end of ${techsas.home} in the first place (is there a way to print the value of ${techsas.home} from within NetBeans?)

Anyway, any help is much appreciated - I'm a bit lost at the moment.

Comment: Which linux distro are you running?

Comment: Does that use Gnome or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Gnome (eg on Ubuntu) you need to set environment variables in `~/.gnomerc` for them to be visible to apps launched from the desktop.

See: [How do I pass an environment variable to a Netbeans Makefile on Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2057605/how-do-i-pass-an-enviroment-variable-to-a-netbeans-makefile-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Hmm, looks like that should be the solution.. It is indeed running Gnome (2.28.2). I created ~/.gnomerc with the required export statements, rebooted, and still nothing - it seems like maybe this isn't being executed, running echo $TECHSAS_HOME at a terminal will return nothing (and I still get the same error in NetBeans)

Comment: @Caligari Maybe try `~/.profile` or one of these other files? http://superuser.com/questions/19044/how-do-i-set-an-environmental-variable-for-a-gnome-session

Answer (score 0):

Well, I worked it out. Kind of.

In the root pom, the project's home directory is defined like this:

```
<techsas.home>${TECHSAS_HOME}</techsas.home>
```

i.e, copy the environment variable $TECHSAS_HOME to the Maven variable techsas.home.

However, for some reason, ${TECHSAS_HOME} isn't resolving - even though the variable is correctly set (via .gnomerc as well as .bashrc - thanks @therefromhere). ${env.TECHSAS_HOME} doesn't work either, and as far as I can tell that's the correct way to do this (eg http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide)

Changing it to the actual path - ie

```
<techsas.home>/usr/local/techsas</techsas.home>
```

makes it work fine. Why it's behaving like this (AFAIK the build scripts in the repo should be correct) is still a mystery to me - but at least I have a work around for the time being.